# How to start RMI via weblogic concole?

Tags: java, weblogic, rmi

i have to migrate a web application to weblogic, and this web app requires RMI to run, in my previous system, i have to execute startRMIregistry.sh which contain of:

```
#!/bin/sh
exist="false"
for var in `ps -ef | grep rmiregistry`
do
    if [ "$var" = "rmiregistry" ]
    then
        exist="true"
    fi
    if [ "$var" = "8206" ]
    then
        if [ "$exist" = "true" ]
        then
            echo "rmiregistry is already running."
            exit
        fi
    fi
done
CLASSPATH=.:/home/cms/server/cms.jar:/home/cms/lib/lucene-1.4.2.jar
export CLASSPATH
rmiregistry 8206 &
echo rmiregistry started
echo $! > rmiregistry.pid
```

and now i need to start this RMI registry via server start argument in weblogic console. I think i need to start via console to make sure RMI server run in my managed server, is this right? I need a suggestion, how can i start RMI as server mode under my managed server?

i am really sorry if my explanation quite confusing, :)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The `Server Start` arguments are not the correct place to run or source a script.

If you need your weblogic server to run a script beforehand, you should modify either `setDomainEnv.sh` or `startWebLogic.sh` and put in a line like:

```
. <path>/startRMIregistry.sh
```

The [IBM support page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLKT6_7.5.0/com.ibm.mbs.doc/fm_sag/configsys/t_create_batch_file_start_rmi_weblogic.html?lang=no) also contains good information on renaming `startWebLogic` to `startRMIReigistry`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, i'm trying to make connection between 2 managed server in my weblogic, but i don't know how to setup this connection. Lets say i have cms_server and home_server. I want to make connection between those managed server over RMI, how can i accomplish this? thank you very much :)